# Adding "meta" info to WP site PHP function?

Tags: custom-field, multisite

I'm asking for some grace on this question - I lack sufficient knowledge of both WP and PHP to be more specific ... so here goes:

I'd like to associate some "meta" information about my website into the content; for example a tree (e.g. Maple), so that I can use a PHP tag (and/or shortcode) to say something like `<? echo $tree ?>` and get a value printed out. The reason for this is because I'm planning to set up multiple sites using MU with a different focus and some of the content will be dynamic and some manual.

What is the recommended way in WordPress to do something like this? Is this something I can define in `functions.php` and then grab at my leisure?

PS - is this possibly a custom field thing? I may want this content to appear anywhere (header, sidebar, footer, in page content [etc.])

Comment: Do you need a backend interface for this or are you happy with hard-coded data? Is this "meta" information site-wide or network-wide?

Answer (score 2):

- Store site specific data in [regular options](http://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API). See `add_option()`, `get_option()` and so on.
- Store options for the complete network in a *site option*. See `add_site_option()` and related functions.

You can add new fields for these options in a [separate admin page](https://github.com/toscho/T5-Admin-Menu-Demo) or use an existing page for that. For the latter see my plugin [Public Contact Data](https://github.com/toscho/Public-Contact-Data) which does exactly what are asking for. It adds dynamic [shortcodes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) too. :)

Comment: Thanks for the responding question and answer; I've decided not to use WPMU at this point and hard code it instead :)